# How to get User in kernel response in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am making simple api wrapper, so all requests to `https://example.comA/api/me` must be catched on kernel response level and forwarded to `https://api.example.comB/me` and all was fine however I cannot get the currently logged in User in that kernel response because it returns null:

```
namespace App\Manager\Api\Event;

use App\Provider\Core\Api\CoreApi;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class ApiWrapperEventListener
{
    private $coreApi;
    private $security;

    public function __construct(CoreApi $coreApi, Security $security)
    {
        $this->coreApi = $coreApi;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) return;

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ('/api' === substr($request->getPathInfo(), 0, 4)) {
            dump($this->security->getUser()); // returns NULL
            die;

            try {
                $response = $this->coreApi->call($request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo(), json_decode($request->getContent(), true) ?? []);
                $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse($response));
            } catch (BadResponseException $error) {
                dump($error);
                die;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess Symfony is firing those events before I get the User, is there a way to get this right?

I have to note that in other places like controllers or services I get the User right.

Comment: Can you check the priority? Easiest way to find out is `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request`. Your event should have a lower priority than the firewall listener. edit: actually, nevermind. Response event should not have this issue. Do you have the profiler enabled? Your response should have a debug header with a link to the profile, where you can check the authentication layer

Comment: Are you hitting a controller or something, maybe you should try to dump user from there. Looks like there is actually no user logged in. Are you sending some sort of a  token or a cookie with your request?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i know what was the problem.

The response controller event has no User when 404 or 500 given.

In my case I was catching 404, passing to listener and modifying the request to 200.

This approach wasn't good, so i decided to move this to Controller itself.

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/api/v1/{uri}", name="api", requirements={"uri"=".+"})
     */
    public function api(
        Request  $request,
        CoreApi  $coreApi
    ):Response
    {
        try
        {
            $response = $coreApi->call($request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo(), json_decode($request->getContent(), true) ?? []);
            return new JsonResponse($response);
        }
        catch(BadResponseException $error)
        {
            return new Response($error->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(), $error->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```